# Is there any problem with using yomtov candles to cook food (on yomtov)?

Tags: halacha, food, chagim-holidays, cooking-bishul, candle-lighting

Suppose you had a lot of candles, and a small pan of chocolate you wanted to melt, any problem using the yomtov candles for this?  Cooking is permitted, but is the use of yomtov candles restricted in any way?  Is it considered degrading of the mitzva?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard not to use them, though that doesn't necessarily mean it's okay; and I do know that people use the *yom tov* candles to light stoves. As always, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).